# Recurse Over Excel File To Find Top Level Item From Tree Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, recursion, tree

I'm trying to recurse over a dataset to find the highest level item, i.e. one that does not have a parent.

The structure looks like this:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╗
║    Item    ║  Material  ║
╠════════════╬════════════╣
║ 2094-00003 ║ MHY00007   ║
║ 2105-0001  ║ 2105-0002  ║
║ 2105-0002  ║ 2105-1000  ║
║ 2105-1000  ║ 2105-1003  ║
║ 2105-1003  ║ 7547-122   ║
║ 7932-00001 ║ 7932-00015 ║
║ 7932-00002 ║ 7932-00015 ║
║ 7932-00010 ║ MHY00007   ║
║ 7932-00015 ║ 7932-05000 ║
║ 7932-05000 ║ MHY00007   ║
╚════════════╩════════════╝
```

So, for example, if I select 7547-122, the function will return 2105-0001. So the function has recursively followed the tree upwards, 7547-122 -> 2105-1003 -> 2105-1000 -> … -> 2105-0001.

When I run my code, I can only get it to return one top level, as you can see from the MHY00007 case, some times there are multiple top levels. How can I return a list of all the top levels any given material has?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd


class BillOfMaterials:

    def __init__(self, bom_excel_path):
        self.df = pd.read_excel(bom_excel_path)
        self.df = self.df[['Item', 'Material']]

    def find_parents(self, part_number):
        material_parent_search = self.df[self.df.Material == part_number]

        parents = list(set(material_parent_search['Item']))

        return parents

    def find_top_levels(self, parents):

        top_levels = self.__ancestor_finder_([parents])

        print(f'{parents} top level is {top_levels}')
        return {parents: top_levels}

    def __ancestor_finder_(self, list_of_items):

        for ancestor in list_of_items:
            print(f'Searching for ancestors of {ancestor}')
            ancestors = self.find_parents(ancestor)
            print(f'{ancestor} has ancestor(s) {ancestors}')

            if not ancestors:
                return ancestor
            else:
                highest_level = self.__ancestor_finder_(ancestors)
        return highest_level


BOM = BillOfMaterials(bom_excel_path="Path/To/Excel/File/BOM.xlsx")

ItemsToSearch = ['7547-122', 'MHY00007']

top_levels = []
for item in ItemsToSearch:
    top_levels.append(BOM.find_top_levels(item))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this recursively, for example:

```
import pandas as pd


class BillOfMaterials:

    def __init__(self, bom_excel_path):
        self.df = pd.read_excel(bom_excel_path)
        self.df = self.df[['Item', 'Material']]

    def find_parents(self, part_number):
        return list(set(self.df[self.df.Material == part_number]['Item']))

    def find_top_levels(self, item):
        parents = self.find_parents(item)
        if not parents:
            # there are no parent items => this item is a leaf
            return [item]
        else:
            # there are parent items => recursively find grandparents
            grandparents = []
            for parent in parents:
                grandparents = grandparents + self.find_top_levels(parent)
            return grandparents


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BOM = BillOfMaterials(bom_excel_path="testdata.xlsx")
    ItemsToSearch = ['7547-122', 'MHY00007']

    for i in ItemsToSearch:
        print('')
        print('The top levels of ' + i + ' are: ')
        print(BOM.find_top_levels(i))
```

Note the recursive call of `self.find_top_levels(parent)`. 
This will give the output

```
The top levels of 7547-122 are: 
['2105-0001']

The top levels of MHY00007 are: 
['2094-00003', '7932-00001', '7932-00002', '7932-00010']
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion over a `pandas` dataframe will be slower than using a `dict`.

For performance, I recommend you create a dictionary and create a simple function to iteratively cycle up your tree structure. Below is an example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['2094-00003', '2105-0001', '2105-0002', '2105-1000',
                            '2105-1003', '7932-00001', '7932-00002', '7932-00010',
                            '7932-00015', '7932-05000'],
                   'Material': ['MHY00007', '2105-0002', '2105-1000', '2105-1003',
                                '7547-122', '7932-00015', '7932-00015', 'MHY00007',
                                '7932-05000', 'MHY00007']})

parent_child = df.set_index('Item')['Material'].to_dict()
child_parent = {v: k for k, v in parent_child.items()}

def get_all_parents(x):
    while x in child_parent:
        x = child_parent[x]
        yield x

def get_grand_parent(x):
    for last in get_all_parents(x):
        pass
    return last

get_grand_parent('7547-122')
# '2105-0001'
```